# Error in Grizzly HTTP Server (Jersey) when incorporating ArcGIS Runtime SDK for Java

Tags: java, jersey, arcgis-runtime

I followed the guide [here](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/getting-started.html)  to create a new Jersey HTTP server from Maven Archetype. Everything is fine, the resource returns the string as expected, here is the resource:

```
package com.example;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

@Path("myresource")
    public class MyResource {

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String getIt() {         

        return "Hello from my Server";
}
}
```

I followed the guide [here](https://developers.arcgis.com/java/latest/guide/develop-your-first-map-app.htm) to use the downloaded ArcGIS Runtime SDK. I created the following simple Java class to determine whether a Point in inside a Geometry (Circle, Rectangle, Polygon, ...) or not:

```
package geoC;
import com.esri.arcgisruntime.geometry.Geometry;
import com.esri.arcgisruntime.geometry.GeometryEngine;
import com.esri.arcgisruntime.geometry.Point;
import com.esri.arcgisruntime.geometry.SpatialReferences;

public class checkInside {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Point pt = new Point( -0.04473405456542423, 39.98776978688296, SpatialReferences.getWgs84());       

    String rectangleJson = "{\"xmin\":-0.05225854142896743,\"ymin\":39.98251082423102,\"xmax\":-0.02856927140946811,\"ymax\":39.993164240959295,\"spatialReference\":{\"wkid\":4326}}";
    Geometry rectangle = (Geometry) Geometry.fromJson(rectangleJson);       

    //check if the point is inside the rectangle or not
    boolean decision = GeometryEngine.contains( rectangle, pt );            
    System.out.println(decision);
    }
}
```

This class works fine, producing "true" or "false" depending on the location input.

The problem arises when I tried to combine the first and the second piece of code, I put the content of the 2nd piece of code in the first piece of code:

```
package com.example;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import com.esri.arcgisruntime.geometry.Geometry;
import com.esri.arcgisruntime.geometry.GeometryEngine;
import com.esri.arcgisruntime.geometry.Point;
import com.esri.arcgisruntime.geometry.SpatialReferences;

@Path("myresource")
public class MyResource {

@GET
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
public String getIt() {  

    Point pt = new Point( -0.04473405456542423, 39.98776978688296, SpatialReferences.getWgs84());       

    String rectangleJson = "{\"xmin\":-0.05225854142896743,\"ymin\":39.98251082423102,\"xmax\":-0.02856927140946811,\"ymax\":39.993164240959295,\"spatialReference\":{\"wkid\":4326}}";
    Geometry rectangle = (Geometry) Geometry.fromJson(rectangleJson);       

    boolean decision = GeometryEngine.contains( rectangle, pt );        
    System.out.println(decision);

    return "Hello from my Server";
}
}
```

mvn compile   ---> BUILD SUCCESS

mvn exec:java ---> BUILD FAILURE

The error is: Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:java (default-cli) on project TestArcGISJersey: An exception occured while executing the Java class. null: InvocationTargetException: com/esri/arcgisruntime/geometry/Geometry: com.esri.arcgisruntime.geometry.Geometry -> [Help 1]

Furthermore, if I comment the 2 lines (boolean decision = ... + System.out.println(...) ) then mvn exec:java executes succesfully, but when I send a GET request to the resource, request failed instead of getting the expected String.

Anyone has any ideas here? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that you have not gotten any licence yet, remember that all ArcGIS products need to have a licence, does not matter if you pay or not.

I kindly suggest you to follow this steps from ArcGIS Developers (ArcGIS runtime for JAVA 100.0.0) ["License your app"](https://developers.arcgis.com/java/latest/guide/license-your-app.htm)

There you can see that you need a line like this:

https://developers.arcgis.com/java/latest/guide/license-your-app.htm

```
    // license with a license key
ArcGISRuntimeEnvironment.setLicense("runtimelite,1000,rud#########,day-month-year,####################");
```

I am not sure about using ArcGIS runtime on a Jersey HTTP server from Maven Archetype. you will need additional tests and always look to the server log.

Answer (score 0):

ArcGIS Runtime SDK for Java is not a good candidate as an API to use in a server environment. While some APIs may work, this use case is not supported. The API was not designed for use in server containers.

However, for your use case you've described, you may want to look at the Java Geometry API open source project found here: https://github.com/Esri/geometry-api-java.

Still, having stated the reality of this, I do feel it is natural to assume it would be a viable solution for server development. So great question!